# Concat string in JOLT

Tags: json, mapping, transformation, jolt

I am trying to contact two strings in JOLT. The fields are 'WG_REQ_FIRST_NAME + WG_REQ_LAST_NAME'.

What I want-

WG_REQ_FIRST_NAME - Tom

WG_REQ_LAST_NAME - Jones

**requesterDetails**- Tom Jones

Path at which I want the data - IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.requesterDetails

What I tried-

```
    {
        "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
        "spec": {
            "requestorDetails": "=concat(@(1,WG_REQ_FIRST_NAME),' ',@(1,WG_REQ_LAST_NAME))"
        }
    }
```

I later then called the field but it is not showing in output-

```
"requestorDetails": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.requesterDetails",
```

Input-

```
{
    "PURCHASE_ORDER_DISPATCH": {
        "MsgData": {
            "Transaction": {
                "PO_POD_HDR_EVW1": {
                    "WG_ADDR_SEQ_NUM": 1,
                    "WG_PO_CNTCT_EMAIL": "PeggyMeincke@westfieldgrp.com",
                    "WG_REQUESTOR_EMAIL": "ZacharyEngels@westfieldgrp.com",
                    "WG_REQ_FIRST_NAME": "Zachary",
                    "WG_REQ_LAST_NAME": "Engels",
                    "WG_DELIVER_TO": "ZacharyEngels@westfieldgrp.com",
                    "BUSINESS_UNIT": "OFIC",
                    "PO_ID": 25052,
                    "VENDOR_SETID": "WCOS",
                    "VENDOR_ID": 35958,
                    "VNDR_LOC": 1,
                    "PO_DT": "2020-01-24",
                    "DB_NUMBER_BU": "",
                    "DESCR_BU": "OhioFarmersInsuranceCo",
                    "ADDRESS1_BU": "WESTFIELDCOMPANIES",
                    "ADDRESS2_BU": "HOMEOFFICE",
                    "ADDRESS3_BU": "1PARKCIRCLE",
                    "ADDRESS4_BU": "",
                    "CITY_BU": "WESTFIELDCENTER",
                    "STATE_BU": "OH",
                    "POSTAL_BU": "44251-5001",
                    "COUNTRY_BU": "USA",
                    "ADDRESS1_BILL": "",
                    "ADDRESS2_BILL": "",
                    "ADDRESS3_BILL": "",
                    "ADDRESS4_BILL": "",
                    "CITY_BILL": "",
                    "STATE_BILL": "",
                    "POSTAL_BILL": "",
                    "COUNTRY_BILL": "",
                    "CURRENCY_CD": "USD",
                    "TAX_EXEMPT_ID": "",
                    "STD_ID_NUM_VNDR": "",
                    "NAME1_VNDR": "AMAZONCAPITALSERVICESINC",
                    "ADDRESS1_VNDR": "410TERRYAVEN",
                    "ADDRESS2_VNDR": "",
                    "ADDRESS3_VNDR": "",
                    "ADDRESS4_VNDR": "",
                    "CITY_VNDR": "SEATTLE",
                    "STATE_VNDR": "WA",
                    "POSTAL_VNDR": 98109,
                    "COUNTRY_VNDR": "USA",
                    "PYMNT_TERMS_CD": "NET30",
                    "DESCR50_PAY": "Net30",
                    "BUYER_ID": 1083,
                    "PO_AMT_TTL": 14.99,
                    "TEXT254_CC1": "",
                    "TEXT254_CC2": "",
                    "VNDR_UPN_FLG": "N",
                    "STD_ID_NUM_VNDRGLN": "",
                    "STD_ID_NUM_BILLTO": "",
                    "ATTN_TO": "ZacharyEngels",
                    "PO_POD_LN_EVW1": {
                        "WG_REQ_ID": 25694,
                        "WG_CATEGORY_CD": "FSSUP",
                        "WG_ITEM_TYPE": 0,
                        "WG_ACCOUNT": 641100,
                        "WG_DEPT_ID": 30400,
                        "WG_PRODUCT": "",
                        "BUSINESS_UNIT": "OFIC",
                        "PO_ID": 25052,
                        "WG_ASSET_GROUP": "",
                        "WG_CAPITALIZE": "NO",
                        "WG_PROFILE_ID": "",
                        "WG_SPLIT_TYPE": 1,
                        "WG_ASSET_LOC": "HOME",
                        "WG_PROJECT": "",
                        "VENDOR_SETID": "WCOS",
                        "VENDOR_ID": 35958,
                        "VNDR_LOC": 1,
                        "LINE_NBR": 1,
                        "INV_ITEM_ID": "",
                        "DESCR254_MIXED": "147-1518156-3620845,1GreenMountainCoffeeRoastersCaramelVanillaCreamKeurigSingle-ServeK-CupPods,LightRoastCoffee,32Count",
                        "UNIT_OF_MEASURE": "EA",
                        "ITM_ID_VNDR": "B0798CX2Q9",
                        "VNDR_CATALOG_ID": "",
                        "MFG_ID": "",
                        "MFG_ITM_ID": 5000196305,
                        "CNTRCT_ID": "",
                        "VERSION_NBR": 0,
                        "CNTRCT_LINE_NBR": 0,
                        "CAT_LINE_NBR": 0,
                        "RELEASE_NBR": 0,
                        "CANCEL_STATUS": "A",
                        "UPN_ID": "",
                        "PO_POD_SHP_EVW1": {
                            "WG_SHIP_ADDR_TYPE": 0,
                            "WG_CUST_ADDR_CODE": "OFIC",
                            "BUSINESS_UNIT": "OFIC",
                            "PO_ID": 25052,
                            "VENDOR_SETID": "WCOS",
                            "VENDOR_ID": 35958,
                            "VNDR_LOC": 1,
                            "LINE_NBR": 1,
                            "SCHED_NBR": 1,
                            "DUE_DT": "2020-01-29",
                            "SHIPTO_ID": "OFIC"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Spec-

```
[
    {
        "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
        "spec": {
            "requestorDetails": "=concat(@(1,WG_REQ_FIRST_NAME),' ',@(1,WG_REQ_LAST_NAME))"
        }
    },
    {
        "operation": "shift",
        "spec": {
            "#integrationTrackingNumber": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityHeader.integrationTrackingNumber",
            "#referenceCodeForEntity": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityHeader.referenceCodeForEntity",
            "#additionalInfo": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityHeader.additionalInfo",
            "*": {
                "*": {
                    "*": {
                        "*": {
                            "PO_ID": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.externalId",
                            "#APPROVED": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.status",
                            "PO_AMT_TTL": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.grossTotalAmount",
                            "#test.test\\@test.com": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.checkoutBuyer.userEmailId",
                            "requestorDetails": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.requesterDetails",
                            "FREIGHT_TERMS": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.deliveryTermCode",
                            "WG_REQUESTOR_EMAIL": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.requesterDetails.userEmailId",
                            "WG_DELIVER_TO": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.deliverTo.userEmailId",
                            "#OFIC": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.company.companyCode",
                            "BUSINESS_UNIT": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.businessUnit.buCode",
                            "PYMNT_TERMS_CD": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.paymentTermId",
                            "#1": [
                                "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.costingSplitLevel",
                                "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.costingSplitType"
                            ],
                            "WG_ADDR_SEQ_NUM": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.supplierAddress.addressERPID",
                            "CURRENCY_CD": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.supplierCurrencyCode",
                            "@WG_ADDR_SEQ_NUM": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.supplierAddressERPID",
                            "VENDOR_ID": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.supplierERPID",
                            "WG_PO_CNTCT_EMAIL": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.suppPOContactEmail",
                            "#2": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.supplierPOContactType",
                            "WG_REQ_FIRST_NAME": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.requesterDetails.userFirstName",
                            "WG_REQ_LAST_NAME": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.requesterDetails.userLastName",
                            "@CURRENCY_CD": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.currency",
                            "@WG_DELIVER_TO": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.deliverToUser.userEmailId",
                            "*": {
                                "WG_REQ_ID": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.poDescription",
                                "#STANDARD": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.poType",
                                "LINE_NBR": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.lineNumber",
                                "WG_CATEGORY_CD": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.categoryCode",
                                "WG_ITEM_TYPE": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.itemType",
                                "MFG_ITM_ID": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.manufacturerPartID",
                                "ITM_ID_VNDR": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.supplierPartID",
                                "WG_ACCOUNT": {
                                    "@": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[0].value",
                                    "#name4": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[0].id",
                                    "#AUTO_COMPLETE": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[0].type",
                                    "#GL_ACCOUNT": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[0].name"
                                },
                                "WG_DEPT_ID": {
                                    "@": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[1].value",
                                    "#name3": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[1].id",
                                    "#AUTO_COMPLETE": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[1].type",
                                    "#Westfield Department": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[1].name"
                                },
                                "WG_PRODUCT": {
                                    "@": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[2].value",
                                    "#name6": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[2].id",
                                    "#AUTO_COMPLETE": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[2].type",
                                    "#Product/Parcel": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[2].name"
                                },
                                "WG_PROJECT": {
                                    "@": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[3].value",
                                    "#name5": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[3].id",
                                    "#AUTO_COMPLETE": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[3].type",
                                    "#Project Code": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[3].name"
                                },
                                "WG_ASSET_GROUP": {
                                    "@": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[4].value",
                                    "#name10": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[4].id",
                                    "#AUTO_COMPLETE": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[4].type",
                                    "#Asset Group": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[4].name"
                                },
                                "WG_CAPITALIZE": {
                                    "@": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[5].value",
                                    "#name9": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[5].id",
                                    "#AUTO_COMPLETE": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[5].type",
                                    "#Capitalize": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[5].name"
                                },
                                "WG_PROFILE_ID": {
                                    "@": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[6].value",
                                    "#name9": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[6].id",
                                    "#AUTO_COMPLETE": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[6].type",
                                    "#Profile Id": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[6].name"
                                },
                                "WG_ASSET_LOC": {
                                    "@": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[7].value",
                                    "#name2": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[7].id",
                                    "#AUTO_COMPLETE": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[7].type",
                                    "#Business Unit": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[7].name"
                                },
                                "BUSINESS_UNIT": {
                                    "@": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[8].value",
                                    "#name7": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[8].id",
                                    "#AUTO_COMPLETE": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[8].type",
                                    "#GL_ACCOUNT": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[8].name"
                                },
                                "*": {
                                    "@WG_SHIP_ADDR_TYPE": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.shipToAddressType",
                                    "WG_SHIP_ADDR_TYPE": {
                                        "2": {
                                            "@(2,DESCR_SHIPTO)": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.shipToAddress.addressName",
                                            "@(2,ADDRESS1_SHIPTO)": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.shipToAddress.addressLine1",
                                            "@(2,ADDRESS2_SHIPTO)": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.shipToAddress.addressLine2",
                                            "@(2,ADDRESS3_SHIPTO)": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.shipToAddress.addressLine3",
                                            "@(2,ADDRESS4_SHIPTO)": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.shipToAddress.addressLine4",
                                            "@(2,CITY_SHIPTO)": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.shipToAddress.city",
                                            "@(2,POSTAL_SHIPTO)": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.shipToAddress.zip",
                                            "@(2,STATE_SHIPTO)": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.shipToAddress.state",
                                            "@(2,COUNTRY_SHIPTO)": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.shipToAddress.country"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "WG_CUST_ADDR_CODE": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.shipToAddress.addressCode",
                                    "FREIGHT_TERMS": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.deliveryTermCode",
                                    "SHIPTO_ID": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.locationCode.location.locationCode",
                                    "DUE_DT": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.deliverOn",
                                    "@DUE_DT": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.deliveryOn",
                                    "PRICE_PO": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.marketPrice",
                                    "QTY_PO": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.itemQuantity",
                                    "@WG_CUST_ADDR_CODE": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.shipToAddressCode",
                                    "@WG_SHIP_ADDR_TYPE": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.shipToAddressType",
                                    "#1": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.costingSplitType",
                                    "@WG_CUST_ADDR_CODE": {
                                        "2": {
                                            "@(2,DESCR_SHIPTO)": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.shipToAddress.addressName",
                                            "@(2,ADDRESS1_SHIPTO)": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.shipToAddress.addressLine1",
                                            "@(2,ADDRESS2_SHIPTO)": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.shipToAddress.addressLine2",
                                            "@(2,ADDRESS3_SHIPTO)": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.shipToAddress.addressLine3",
                                            "@(2,ADDRESS4_SHIPTO)": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.shipToAddress.addressLine4",
                                            "@(2,CITY_SHIPTO)": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.shipToAddress.city",
                                            "@(2,POSTAL_SHIPTO)": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.shipToAddress.zip",
                                            "@(2,STATE_SHIPTO)": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.shipToAddress.state",
                                            "@(2,COUNTRY_SHIPTO)": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.shipToAddress.country"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this spec:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "*": {
              "requestorDetails": "=concat(@(1,WG_REQ_FIRST_NAME),' ',@(1,WG_REQ_LAST_NAME))"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
 },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "#integrationTrackingNumber": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityHeader.integrationTrackingNumber",
      "#referenceCodeForEntity": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityHeader.referenceCodeForEntity",
      "#additionalInfo": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityHeader.additionalInfo",
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "*": {
              "requestorDetails": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.requesterDetails",
              "PO_ID": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.externalId",
              "#APPROVED": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.status",
              "PO_AMT_TTL": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.grossTotalAmount",
              "#test.test\\@test.com": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.checkoutBuyer.userEmailId",
              "requestorDetails": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.requesterDetails",
              "FREIGHT_TERMS": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.deliveryTermCode",
              "WG_REQUESTOR_EMAIL": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.requesterDetails.userEmailId",
              "WG_DELIVER_TO": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.deliverTo.userEmailId",
              "#OFIC": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.company.companyCode",
              "BUSINESS_UNIT": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.businessUnit.buCode",
              "PYMNT_TERMS_CD": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.paymentTermId",
              "#1": [
                                "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.costingSplitLevel",
                                "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.costingSplitType"
                            ],
              "WG_ADDR_SEQ_NUM": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.supplierAddress.addressERPID",
              "CURRENCY_CD": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.supplierCurrencyCode",
              "@WG_ADDR_SEQ_NUM": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.supplierAddressERPID",
              "VENDOR_ID": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.supplierERPID",
              "WG_PO_CNTCT_EMAIL": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.suppPOContactEmail",
              "#2": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.supplierPOContactType",
              "WG_REQ_FIRST_NAME": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.requesterDetails.userFirstName",
              "WG_REQ_LAST_NAME": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.requesterDetails.userLastName",
              "@CURRENCY_CD": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.currency",
              "@WG_DELIVER_TO": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.deliverToUser.userEmailId",
              "*": {
                "WG_REQ_ID": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.poDescription",
                "#STANDARD": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.poType",
                "LINE_NBR": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.lineNumber",
                "WG_CATEGORY_CD": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.categoryCode",
                "WG_ITEM_TYPE": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.itemType",
                "MFG_ITM_ID": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.manufacturerPartID",
                "ITM_ID_VNDR": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.supplierPartID",
                "WG_ACCOUNT": {
                  "@": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[0].value",
                  "#name4": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[0].id",
                  "#AUTO_COMPLETE": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[0].type",
                  "#GL_ACCOUNT": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[0].name"
                },
                "WG_DEPT_ID": {
                  "@": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[1].value",
                  "#name3": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[1].id",
                  "#AUTO_COMPLETE": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[1].type",
                  "#Westfield Department": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[1].name"
                },
                "WG_PRODUCT": {
                  "@": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[2].value",
                  "#name6": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[2].id",
                  "#AUTO_COMPLETE": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[2].type",
                  "#Product/Parcel": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[2].name"
                },
                "WG_PROJECT": {
                  "@": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[3].value",
                  "#name5": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[3].id",
                  "#AUTO_COMPLETE": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[3].type",
                  "#Project Code": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[3].name"
                },
                "WG_ASSET_GROUP": {
                  "@": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[4].value",
                  "#name10": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[4].id",
                  "#AUTO_COMPLETE": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[4].type",
                  "#Asset Group": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[4].name"
                },
                "WG_CAPITALIZE": {
                  "@": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[5].value",
                  "#name9": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[5].id",
                  "#AUTO_COMPLETE": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[5].type",
                  "#Capitalize": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[5].name"
                },
                "WG_PROFILE_ID": {
                  "@": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[6].value",
                  "#name9": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[6].id",
                  "#AUTO_COMPLETE": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[6].type",
                  "#Profile Id": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[6].name"
                },
                "WG_ASSET_LOC": {
                  "@": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[7].value",
                  "#name2": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[7].id",
                  "#AUTO_COMPLETE": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[7].type",
                  "#Business Unit": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[7].name"
                },
                "BUSINESS_UNIT": {
                  "@": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[8].value",
                  "#name7": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[8].id",
                  "#AUTO_COMPLETE": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[8].type",
                  "#GL_ACCOUNT": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.validCombinations.itemDetails.validRules.field[8].name"
                },
                "*": {
                  "@WG_SHIP_ADDR_TYPE": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.shipToAddressType",
                  "WG_SHIP_ADDR_TYPE": {
                    "2": {
                      "@(2,DESCR_SHIPTO)": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.shipToAddress.addressName",
                      "@(2,ADDRESS1_SHIPTO)": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.shipToAddress.addressLine1",
                      "@(2,ADDRESS2_SHIPTO)": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.shipToAddress.addressLine2",
                      "@(2,ADDRESS3_SHIPTO)": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.shipToAddress.addressLine3",
                      "@(2,ADDRESS4_SHIPTO)": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.shipToAddress.addressLine4",
                      "@(2,CITY_SHIPTO)": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.shipToAddress.city",
                      "@(2,POSTAL_SHIPTO)": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.shipToAddress.zip",
                      "@(2,STATE_SHIPTO)": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.shipToAddress.state",
                      "@(2,COUNTRY_SHIPTO)": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.shipToAddress.country"
                    }
                  },
                  "WG_CUST_ADDR_CODE": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.shipToAddress.addressCode",
                  "FREIGHT_TERMS": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.deliveryTermCode",
                  "SHIPTO_ID": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.locationCode.location.locationCode",
                  "DUE_DT": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.deliverOn",
                  "@DUE_DT": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.deliveryOn",
                  "PRICE_PO": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.marketPrice",
                  "QTY_PO": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.itemQuantity",
                  "@WG_CUST_ADDR_CODE": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.shipToAddressCode",
                  "@WG_SHIP_ADDR_TYPE": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.shipToAddressType",
                  "#1": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.costingSplitType",
                  "@WG_CUST_ADDR_CODE": {
                    "2": {
                      "@(2,DESCR_SHIPTO)": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.shipToAddress.addressName",
                      "@(2,ADDRESS1_SHIPTO)": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.shipToAddress.addressLine1",
                      "@(2,ADDRESS2_SHIPTO)": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.shipToAddress.addressLine2",
                      "@(2,ADDRESS3_SHIPTO)": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.shipToAddress.addressLine3",
                      "@(2,ADDRESS4_SHIPTO)": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.shipToAddress.addressLine4",
                      "@(2,CITY_SHIPTO)": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.shipToAddress.city",
                      "@(2,POSTAL_SHIPTO)": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.shipToAddress.zip",
                      "@(2,STATE_SHIPTO)": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.shipToAddress.state",
                      "@(2,COUNTRY_SHIPTO)": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.items.item.shipToAddress.country"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    }
]
```